# Reading bit inside 2 byte

Tags: java

```
int id = ((reply[0] & 0x3));
id = (id<<7) | (reply[1] & 0x7F);
```

Suppose I have a reply array storing 2 byte reply[0] and reply[1].
I wanna read the last two bits in the first byte and all the bits in the second byte, then adding them together

why the code above is going to work, can anyone explain?

Comment: actually it should be the last 7 bits in second byte instead of all bits, sorry for making mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to binary and you will get your answer.
binary of 3 is 11. if you use `logical &` with 11 you will end up only with the last two bits. That's the answer to your first part.

For the second part, I don't think it will do what you intended it too. You can use `logical AND` (for carry) and `logical XOR` to add individual bits.

Try to figure it out ^_^

Answer (score 2):

This code is not doing what you described: instead of taking the second byte in its entirety, it cuts out its last seven bits (the `& 0x7F` part; `0x7F` is binary `01111111`), and *concatenates* them to the two last two bits of the first number (the `<< 7` part).

Comment: Thank Sir i got your point, that means (reply[1] & 0x7F) is used for cutting out the last seven bit of the second byte and  id<<7 is used for concatenation with the first byte last two bit, am i right?

But I wonder to get the first byte last two bits, reply[0] & 0x3 is used but not 0x2, also i wonder the program is working with 0x7F ..

Comment: `id << 7` is used to move the three bits into position just before concatenation; the concatenation operation itself is performed by the `|` operator. `0x03` means the "last two bits" because it is binary `00000011`.